# Assembly difference between TASM and MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, tasm

I am learning TASM at University, but information regarding TASM on the web seems to be very limited. I have found more information on MASM.

My question is, what is the different between MASM and TASM?

Comment: For what I have read in articles from matt pietrek TASM builds PE/COFF differently in couple cases, it shouldn't influence the functionality of the code though. Also those articles I have read may be now outdated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There aren't so much differences, but there are some.
Check out this article: https://web.archive.org/web/20200614205011/https://faqs.cs.uu.nl/na-dir/assembly-language/x86/borland.html Look for 'ideal' mode; btw, TASM can work with MASM syntax.

Answer (score 3):

> TASM = **Turbo Assembler** (a Borland product)
>
> MASM = **Macro Assembler** (a Microsoft product)*...often mistaken for
> "Microsoft Assembler"*

In terms of raw assembly language, they should be virtually identical, as they both use x86 op-code instructions. The differences "should" be syntactic sugar.

**An assembly tutorial that uses TASM:**

http://www.petesqbsite.com/sections/tutorials/tuts/doorknob/asm_tutorial1.html

**ArtOfASM reference:**

[http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/artofasm.html](http://cs.smith.edu/%7Ethiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/artofasm.html)

One example I could give is that both assemblers allow the use of "macros", which in some respects is similar to using methods in a higher level language. So you can write a section of assembly code, which accepts some arguments (usually these are set in the registers prior to calling your macro. the macro might be anything between a few lines, to a million lines of assembler...however you might call your macro in just one line...basically MASM and TASM have very small differences, but mostly the same goals, where code re-usability is important.

Its understandable that you cannot find much information on these anymore...they are fast diminishing. Assembly is a niche these days, and many of the old hats have moved onto things like C, C++, and other higher level languages.

You should try looking on YouTube...I can see many TASM tutorials on there...

...A86 assembler...very simple syntax but will compile 64K "command.com" type files.