# What is relation between Status register and Control register?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

While going through Basic I/O in Computer organisation by "carl hamacher" ,i am confused with lots of terminologies.

In Interrupt I/O,Whenever a device raise an interrupt ,Processor Interrupts the program currently being Executed and saves the content Of Program Counter and Status register and then Interrupt is being processed by ISR.Upon completion of ISR ,the return from execution instruction is executed and then the saved status register and PC are restored.It is perfectly clear to me .

But i am stuck in the following points...-:

> there is a flag IE (interrupt enable) ,if it is 1 then Interrupt req from I/O device are accepted .

On the other hand there is one more point .

> The interface of an I/O device includes a control register that contains the information
>   that governs the mode of operation of the device. One bit in this register may be dedicated
>   to interrupt control. The I/O device is allowed to raise interrupt requests only when this bit
>   is set to 1

Now what is this control register  and which bit they are talking about ? is it different than IE flag??? what is relation between Status register and Control register?

Additionally there is one more point

> The information needed to determine whether a device is requesting an interrupt is
>   available in its status register. When the device raises an interrupt request, it sets to 1 a
>   bit in its status register, which we will call the IRQ bit. The simplest way to identify the
>   interrupting device is to have the interrupt-service routine poll all I/O devices in the system.
>   The first device encountered with its IRQ bit set to 1 is the device that should be serviced.
>   An appropriate subroutine is then called to provide the requested service

Please explain relation between these 3 bits  i.e IE,IRQ and control register's bit 
I am totally confused..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this simplified, yet complete, view of the CPU logic behind acknowledging interrupts:

[image: CPU IRQ processing]

The *IE* flag in the *Status register* is used to mask off all the interrupt requests from the *IRQ* pin.
It controls whenever the CPU will process an interrupt when *IRQ* is asserted.
This status register is in the CPU.

---

Now consider this simplified view of a device:

[image: Device generating an IRQ, logic]

The device has a control block that recognises when to generate an interrupt request (the *Interrupt generation logic* in the scheme).
This block outputs a signal to request an interrupt (*IRQreq*) and a set of *n* signals that identify the source/reason of the interrupt (for example, transmission buffer empty vs new data received).

Both these signal will end in the *device status register* but the *IRQreq* can be eventually masked through a *device control register* bit *IRQen*.

If *IRQen* is zero, the device *IRQ* pin will be zero too and no IRQ is requested, furthermore, no bit is set in the status register to indicate that an interrupt has been requested.
The interrupt reason is still written though because the [software can use polling to test the device status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41442007/5801661).

The same ISR can be used to handle multiple devices, so recognising which device actually triggered it is necessary and this is done by inspecting each possible device status register.

---

So there are three registers:

- **CPU status register** Let the software mask interrupts at the CPU level; all interrupts are masked, no matter what device generates them.
- **Device control register** Let the software mask interrupts per device; some device can be prevented from generating an interrupt some not.
- **Device status register** Let the software know about the last generated interrupt (if any). Usually, this is also used to ACK the interrupt.

Comment: IRQ is like IE (interrupt enable)flag which are used to accept/reject the interrupt req ....i.e IE bit have to be 1 if any device wants to process its interrupted  req  ..!! am i right?

Comment: @sourav IRQ is a pin of the device (it is **outside** the dashed box that represents the chip of the device). The device is a **source** of interrupts, it *generates* interrupts. But to be able to generate an interrupt the *IRQen* bit in the control reg must be 1 or the AND will result in 0 and so will *IRQ* (no interrupt requested thus). *IE* and *IRQen* are basically the same concept from two different view: the first is *don't accept interrupts* the second is *don't let interrupts get out*.

Answer (score 0):

Control (IE) - Used to enable or disable a devices ability to request interrupts.  "Is this device allowed to request an interrupt?"

Status (IRQ) - If interrupts are enabled (by the Control), the IRQ will is set to indicate a particular device has requested an interrupt.  "This device is now requesting an interrupt."

I'm not exactly sure where the 3rd bit is, unless its a global (and not per-device) interrupt enable/disable.   Depending on the specific architecture, there is probably per-device IE/IRQ, and also global IE/IRQ, where the global IE overrides the per-device, and the global IRQ is an indication that at least 1 device has its IRQ set.

Comment: Do IRQ flag and IE flag belong to the same status register ?