# how to make pc beep with assembly in a bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, bios

I searched on google but found nothing for assembly bootloader just for msdos and dos box.
I need to make the pc speaker beep in assembly at a frequency and time and then pause and repeat note i am big noob with assembly

Comment: `in` / `out` or non-DOS `int` calls should work the same in a legacy BIOS bootloader environment as from a DOS executable.  (i.e. any `int` other than `int 21h`)

Comment: The speaker is attached to one of the timer (8253) channels.  You need to set the count register to correspond to your beep frequency.   Find a PC/AT hardware reference manual.

Comment: Margaret's answer on [Assembly 8086 - DOSBOX - How to produce beep sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43996835) has code that only uses a DOS call to exit.  It should drop in to any example BIOS MBR bootloader, at least one that correctly uses `org` and makes DS is set to match.  (Remove the CS: overrides to use the correctly-set DS).

Comment: Or [generate sound on the legacy PC speaker with OUT instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43000350) has a bootloader example.